# OpenXML forcing Precompile during publishing in ASP.Net website

Tags: asp.net, openxml, publishing, precompile

We've created an ASP.Net (webforms) web site in VS2015 and everything works as we expect.  The client asked to be able to export data from the site into Excel.  No problem... we've had experience with OpenXML (v 2.5) in WPF, so we went with that.  The export works like a charm and it performs well when we're in the VS IDE.

The issue is when we publish the site to our development server and open a page it takes over half an hour for the page to eventually render.  I know IIS is compiling the site during this time and it always successfully renders a page, eventually.

If we remove the reference to OpenXML and republish it behaves as we've always seen.  If we add OpenXML back and select the option to 'Precompile during publishing' it works as expected as well.

The question is:  why does OpenXML essentially force prcompiling? Is this something specific to OpenXML?  Or do other dll's behave the same?

We're trying to understand what's going on under the hood.  Yes, we can just use the Precompile option (and we probably will) but we want to know why.